# Run integration tests for cucumber with sbt src/it directory

Tags: scala, junit, cucumber, sbt, integration

I have an integration test with cucumber located in src/it directory
how can I run these tests because the JUnit test framework or any other cucumber-scala sbt plugin wants me to define all related stuff in src/test directory

Comment: See this page for changing the default paths in SBT https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html